# How to share repeated methods in groups of applications

Tags: ios, swift

I have some applications that uses same methods, my idea is to put these codes in a library and then add it to those applications.

1. the base codes are changed very frequently and new methods are added frequently too.
2. I want to share the codes just with specific applications

Is adding library good for this situation or any better solutions should be done

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the Answer is **Yes**.
You can just create **private pod** and install it in your app.
If you are updated you pod, then it will be updates(by using `pod repo update`) in **All Your Apps**